# Getting an TypeError for comparing length of two list

Tags: python

I am comparing the lengths of the two lists. I am getting an TypeError.
`TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`

My comparison code is :

`if len(pcs_list) != len(row['item_list'])`

`row['item_list']` is a row in a dataframe.

Both these are lists. But I am not sure why is this error occurring.
Is there any other reason that might be causing this? How is it possible to have a length of list a float?

Comment: try type(pcs_list) and type(row['item_list']) what do they give you?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit].

Comment: `row['item_list']` is a Series so If you do `len(row['item_list'])` you will get the length of your Series if you want to compare elements at particular position then use `iloc/loc`

Comment: @Sujay  in `row['item_list']` , the `item_list` is the column name.

Comment: @AnuragDabas I do not want to compare the elements in lists in this case.

Comment: `if len(pcs_list) != len(int(row['item_list')])` maybe this would work

Comment: @dio both `type(pcs_list) and type(row['item_list'])`   are of type `int`

Comment: @AnuragDabas @MrHola  row['item_list'] has `Nan` value. How should I skip it and go  to `if len(pcs_list) != len(row['item_list'])` conddition

Comment: by `dropna()` method you can do `len(pcs_list) != len(row['item_list'].dropna())`

Answer (score 1):

`pcs_list` or `row['item_list']` or any of them are list if the error is on this line.

If you try to print them just before you should see a float

Comment: row['item_list'] has Nan value. How should I skip it and go to if len(pcs_list) != len(row['item_list']).